# replaceAll Java method to remove "\\n" from String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a simple treatement but I'm stuck

I have something like

```
"\"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAwoAAADwCAYAAACg2ZPDAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU\\neJzt3XecXVW99";

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "\"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAwoAAADwCAYAAACg2ZPDAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU\\neJzt3XecXVW99";
        String filtre1 = value.replaceAll("\"", "");
        String filtre2 = filtre1.replaceAll("\\n", "");
        System.out.println(filtre2);

    }
```

the result is .. I have always "`\n`" I want to remove it

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAwoAAADwCAYAAACg2ZPDAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU\neJzt3XecXVW99
```

Comment: Try printing `filtre2` instead of `filtre1`.

Comment: sorry I just update it

Comment: You remove a `\`  so it stays `\n` and then try to remove `\\n` but does not exist ...

Comment: Use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`.

Comment: Don't use replaceAll to replace substrings. Use replace(). replaceAll() expects a regexp, not a substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe:

```
String filtre2 = filtre1.replaceAll("\\n", "");
```

need to be :

```
String filtre2 = filtre1.replaceAll("\\\\n", "");
```

(sorry i cannot just add comment)

Comment: Or `filtre1.replace("\\n", "")`

Comment: Or `filtre1.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\n"), "")` (which is effectively what `replace` does internally, expect that `replace` also escapes the replacement).

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "\"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAwoAAADwCAYAAACg2ZPDAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU\\neJzt3XecXVW99";
    String filtre1 = value.replaceAll("\"", "");
    String filtre2 = filtre1.replaceAll("\\\\n", "");
    System.out.println(filtre2);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two choices, both of which are in the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "\"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAwoAAADwCAYAAACg2ZPDAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU\\neJzt3XecXVW99";
    System.out.println(value.replace("\"", "").replace("\\n", ""));
    System.out.println(value.replaceAll("\"|\\\\n", ""));
}
```